# React import JSON file, store content in State and render it out

Tags: reactjs

How do I update the state with my JSON data and then output it as list items?

I want to use the setState function in componentDidMount() so that when the page loads it stores the data in state right away and outputs it on the page

```
import React from 'react';
import peopleData from '../persons.json';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      people: []
    }
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    console.log(peopleData);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          //Loop out this.state.people.names here as List Items
        </ul>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

Here is my JSON data im importing to the above.

```
[
 {
   "Name": "Lisa",
   "Age": 100
 },

 {
   "Name": "Bob",
   "Age": 44
 },

 {
   "Name": "Joe",
   "Age": 17
 },

 {
   "Name": "Jesper",
   "Age": 6
 }
]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can't you just assign peopleData as the default state of people property? It works the same way and it's more concise.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      people: peopleData,
    }
  }

  render() {
    const list = this.state.people.map(d => <li>{p.Name} - {p.Age}</li>);
    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          {list}
        </ul>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Haha Thanks so much! I cant believe i didnt think about that,

Comment: You're welcome. Feel free to accept this answer too 